# Javascript saving variable through a scope when using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, scope, xmlhttprequest

```
var mapFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
mapFile.open("GET", "http://localhost:8000/res/map01.txt", true);

mapFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (mapFile.readyState === 4) {
    if (mapFile.status === 200) {
      this.lines = mapFile.responseText.split("\n");
    }
  }
}

this.lines = mapFile.onreadystatechange.lines;

mapFile.send(null);
```

I have that code and I'm trying to save `this.lines` inside `mapFile.onreadstatechange` to later save as `this.lines` on the outer scope. However, `mapFile.onreadystatachange.lines` is undefined and I can't save the variable for later use. I even tried using `element.innerHTML` which is a dirty hack for this but it also didn't work.

Comment: JS has function-scope. So your `this` within the `onreadystatechange` callback is **different** from the one outside. Pass the outside `this` into it.

Comment: I tried to do `var outsideScope = this;` outside and then try to access `outsideScope` on the inside but it didn't work. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three primary issues here:

1. The `this` within `onreadystatechange` is not the same as the `this` outside of the function, because `this` within a function is determined by how the function is called. More on my blog: [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html) | [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)
2. XHR calls are *asynchronous* (by default), so your callback won't have been called yet when you're trying to use `this.lines` just above the `send` call. (Even with a synchronous request, since that line is *before* `send`, it still wouldn't be set.)
3. `mapFile.onreadystatechange.lines` looks for a property called `lines` on the function object referenced by `mapFile.onreadystatechange`. It has absolutely nothing to do with any variables defined *within* that function.

Here's an update addressing the main items:

```
var mapFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
var self = this; // <===== Remember `this` for use in the callback
mapFile.open("GET", "http://localhost:8000/res/map01.txt", true);

mapFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (mapFile.readyState === 4) {
    if (mapFile.status === 200) {
      // v---- Use self instead of this
      self.lines = mapFile.responseText.split("\n");
    }
  }
}; // <=== Add missing semicolon

// Removed a line here using `this.lines` prematurely

mapFile.send(null);
```